# SQL - Date range Return all data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple PHP web app for daily attendance of empployee
I have a table named `emp_master` it would have all the employee data
for example

```
emp_id   emp_name
1001     Abby
1002     Buub
```

And another table named `timesheet_tran` with dailt transaction when even employee log into the system

```
timesheet_tran table
date       emp_id 
02/01/14   1001
02/01/14   1002
03/01/14   1001
04/01/14   1001
04/01/14   1002
```

I was trying to figure out a single query to return data , between date range which would display all the employees who have logged / not logged for that day between the date range.

i need to display

```
emp_id   date      absent/present
1001     02/01/14  present
1002     02/01/14  present
1001     03/01/14  present
1002     03/01/14  absent
```

i tried

```
SELECT m.emp_id,t.date FROM timesheet_tran as t RIGHT OUTER JOIN emp_master m ON t.date BETWEEN '02/01/14' AND '04/01/14' AND t.emp_id = m.emp_id
```

but I need records for each date mentioned.

Comment: some thing like i have a loop in PHP for ( from to date ) { execute the query for each date individually }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this

```
Select emp_id,emp_name,Date1,(
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
sELECT emp_id FROM timesheet_tran AT WHERE T.emp_id =AT.emp_id AND T.date1=AT.date
) then 'Present' Else 'Absent' End )as Status
FROM
(
Select emp_id ,emp_name,Cast(date as DATE)AS DATE1 from emp_master a,(Select Distinct date    from timesheet_tran ) b
) T
```

## [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20453/6)

Hope this help you

Comment: Dude,,, your awesome , can you please suggest some good way to learn how to write this kind queries.  This works perfectly fine :D

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.emp_id,t.date 
FROM timesheet_tran as t 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN emp_master m ON t.date 
AND t.date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-04-01'
 AND t.emp_id = m.emp_id
```

EDIT: From your updated comments, you need to query a join for all users in a manner that they will be listed whether they are present or not.

```
SELECT m.emp_id,t.date 
FROM emp_master as m 
LEFT JOIN timesheet_tran t ON date
```

This will list all users entries. Where the timesheet data is not present, a null will be returned. You can then convert this to string absent/present as you see fit.

```
    SELECT m.emp_id, 
CASE WHEN t.date IS NOT NULL 
       THEN 'present'
       ELSE 'absent'
END AS T_date
FROM emp_master as m 
LEFT JOIN timesheet_tran t ON date
```

Comment: is this the same i have mentioned above ?

Comment: No, Notice the 'AND t.date' on line 4

Comment: Also, be careful of the default mysql date format : See here for a discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367721/mysql-date-format

Comment: This would return the employee whose are absent between the date range only once

Comment: I didnt know , but i want all the employee for each of the date , if they are absent / present