# MySQL date-type DATE format storage

Tags: mysql, date, format

MySQL datatype `'Date'` stores the date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, is there any way to change the storage format?

I don't want to play on the application layer, I need this thing on database layer instead of performing format checks on the application level.

I want MySQL table to store the date as `dd-mm-yyyy` instead of  `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Date is stored as int internally, displayed as yyyy-mm-dd by default, you can convert your data into default format before saving, and convert to your format when achieve

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible but you can use DATE_FORMAT

```
SELECT Date_format(datefield, '%d-%m-%Y') 
FROM   yourtable
```

Comment: I know about formatting the data, just wanted to know whether I can change the storage format or not

Comment: okais....then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367721/mysql-date-format may help you.